# Can short dates be converted to long dates using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I have an XML data file that contains short dates in this format 10/25/2015.

We want to have the dates display in long format like this Sunday, October 25

Is this possible with XSLT?

Here's some sample data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Guide>
<SessionDay><startDate>10/24/2015</startDate>
<sessions>
<Session_Title>Leadership Development</Session_Title>
</sessions>
</SessionDay>
<SessionDay><startDate>10/25/2015</startDate>
<sessions>
<Session_Title>Teambuilding and Teamwork</Session_Title>
</sessions>
</SessionDay>
</Guide>
```

Comment: It could, but it could be quite ugly (the process to do the conversion).  I did date conversions in XSLT many many years ago, and it was not pretty.

Comment: I thought it would be hard. Luckily, there are only a handful of dates in the final data

Comment: "*Luckily, there are only a handful of dates in the final data*" That makes no difference: the code to convert one is the same as the code to convert a hundred.

Comment: Consider using a general purpose programming language like C#, Java, Python, PHP, etc. in addition to XSLT as they come equipped with CPU system functions like `Date()` and `Now()` and time conversions between Unix and formatted strings like long and short date, 12 or 24 hour times.

Comment: @Parfait Upgrading to XSLT 2.0 would be a more appropriate suggestion, IMHO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible, but not easy:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="startDate">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:call-template name="format-date"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="format-date">
    <!-- extract date parameters -->
    <xsl:variable name="month" select="substring-before(., '/')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="day" select="substring-before(substring-after(., '/'), '/')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="year" select="substring-after(substring-after(., '/'), '/')"/>
    <!-- month name -->
    <xsl:variable name="month-name">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$month=1">January</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$month=2">February</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$month=3">March</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$month=4">April</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$month=5">May</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$month=6">June</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$month=7">July</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$month=8">August</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$month=9">September</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$month=10">October</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$month=11">November</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$month=12">December</xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
    <!-- day of week -->
    <xsl:variable name="JDN">
        <xsl:call-template name="JDN">
            <xsl:with-param name="year" select="$year" />
            <xsl:with-param name="month" select="$month" />
            <xsl:with-param name="day" select="$day" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="dayOfweek" select="($JDN + 1) mod 7"/>
    <xsl:variable name="day-name">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$dayOfweek=0">Sunday</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$dayOfweek=1">Monday</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$dayOfweek=2">Tuesday</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$dayOfweek=3">Wednesday</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$dayOfweek=4">Thursday</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$dayOfweek=5">Friday</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$dayOfweek=6">Saturday</xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
    <!-- output -->
    <xsl:value-of select="concat($day-name, ', ', $month-name, ' ', $day)"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="JDN">
    <xsl:param name="year"/>
    <xsl:param name="month"/>
    <xsl:param name="day"/>
    <xsl:variable name="a" select="floor((14 - $month) div 12)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="y" select="$year + 4800 - $a"/>
    <xsl:variable name="m" select="$month + 12*$a - 3"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$day + floor((153*$m + 2) div 5) + 365*$y + floor($y div 4) - floor($y div 100) + floor($y div 400) - 32045" />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You're right. It's not pretty. But it works. Fabulous.